# How does Spring Security differentiate between multiple logged in user

Tags: spring-security

I am working on a Spring-MVC application where I am using spring security for authentication. for accessing secured functions, it is compulsory that the user is logged in. I am using a function where it can be determined whether the user is logged in or not.

I just wanted to know if the code I am posting below will hold if there are multiple users logged in at the same time, to distinguish like user A has logged in. If not, any solutions or ideas. Thank you.

```
Person Controller :
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    private PersonService personService;

// Now whenever there are secure functions to be accessed, like below, I use it the following way :
 }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/note/list/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listNotes(@ModelAttribute("notices") Notes p,@PathVariable int id,Model model) {
Person person = personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
model.addAttribute("section1",this.notesService.listNotesBySectionId(1,person));
}
```

Get currently authenticated user function :

```
@Override
    public Person getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String authenticatedUserId = authentication.getName();

        Person person = personDAO.findPersonByUsername(authenticatedUserId);
        return person;
    }
```

I am implementing authentication this way :

```
@Transactional
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired private PersonDAO personDAO;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

    private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException,DataAccessException {
        Person person = personDAO.findPersonByUsername(username);
            if(person == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");} //Never specify which one was it exactly
        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(person);
    }
}
```

Assembling the user

```
@Transactional
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired private PersonDAO personDAO;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

    private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException,DataAccessException {
        Person person = personDAO.findPersonByUsername(username);
            if(person == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");} 
        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(person);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SecurityContextHolder is internally implemented with a ThreadLocal. This is the default strategy spring security uses and it is proper for web applications. 
Since a ThreadLocal is isolated to the scope of the current thread your code has access to the current user's information only no matter how many others are currently logged in.

In your code however you should check for null authentication objects unless you have enabled anonymous authentication.

```
String authenticatedUserId = authentication.getName();
```

authentication may be null in the line above.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. So conclusion is the above code can handle multiple authentications. I will check if the String is null.

Comment: Haven't run your code to see if it is error free, apart from the authentication stuff. I just say that spring security handles this out of the box.

Comment: Code throws no error at this point, user logs in, I am also able to get the currently logged in user and all. I just forgot to handle the null authentication part...Any idea how can I handle that exception. I don't want to show some Apache Error page.

Comment: You can avoid having null authentication objects by configuring anonymous authentication. It is enabled by default but also depends on your configuration. Check with spring security docs of how to correctly use it. On the other hand if your code is called only from secured resources, you won't have null authentication objects at present, but it may be fragile in case of future code evolution

Comment: Then I guess I don't need to worry about anonymous authentication as code change is not going to be that much. Thank you for everything.